# Preserve meta information while Crop or Scale

Tags: android, android-camera

I capture Image in my camera application (in app camera) and save it to the file system. In file system, it shows me all the meta details like resolution, ISO, Aperture, Date, rotation etc. when I press "Details" button.

But when I crop the same image i lost all this meta information. How can preserver this information in cropped version too.

Comment: Can you clarify what you are doing to crop the image?  The solution to this seems simple, which leads me to question my understanding of the question.

Comment: I am using standard Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(dstRect.width(), dstRect.height(), Config.ARGB_8888); I am not using crop intent for image cropping

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this class personally but it looks like it will do what you need.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface.html

You'll need to get all the attributes you want from the original image file, and save them on your cropped copy. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks @Dave. This seems promising. Let me try this out.